# Exchange: how to change ownership on recurring public folder calendar items?

Tags: permissions, exchange, public-folders

Our public folders live on Exchange 2010 (recently migrated from Exchange 2007) and Outlook 2007 clients. We use public folder calendars for appointment booking. Here is the usual workflow.

- Amar creates a weekly appointment slot for Bella as a recurring series.
- To fill an appointment slot, Carlos opens one occurrence of the series, invites Bella, enters the information and sends an update.
- Bella gets this update as a meeting reminder.

Both Amar and Carlos are in a group "Appointment Bookers" that has Editor permissions on the public folder.

At some point Amar leaves the company. We disable or remove his account. Now when Carlos tries to book an appointment for Bella, he can edit the occurrence in the series and can modify the occurrence. But when he sends the meeting reminder to Bella he gets the following message:

> You are not allowed to send this message because you are trying to send on
>   behalf of another sender without permission to do so. Please verify that you
>   are sending on behalf of the correct sender, or ask your system administrator
>   to help you get the required permission.

As the system administrator, I would like to help Carlos get the required permission, but I am struggling. I can see a bunch of IPM.Appointment entries using ExFolders, and I can see lots of properties for each appointment, but I do not know what to change, and I do not know how recurring appointments are represented.

Here are some solutions I am considering:

- Leaving Amar's account open forever. This works but is obviously not ideal.
- Ending the recurrence and getting another user (say Darlene) to start a new recurring appointment slot. This is probably my default solution, but I had better hope that Darlene never leaves the company.
- Making some dummy account and then resuming the recurrence with that account.

Is there a better/easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By design the organizer of a meeting cannot be changed.It is stored in a read-only manner, upon creation of a meeting. Being set that way, it cannot be changed with anything like impersonation, delegate access, etc. as it is unchangeable.

Along the lines of what you stated, the best solution to this would be to set the end date as the original user, so all past meeting occurrences would still be displayed on user's calendars. Then start a new meeting occurrence from that date on, as a new user (whether you use a "dummy" account is up to you - I am a fan of using a "dummy/role" account for things just like this).

Comment: Thanks. I found some documentation that indicates the same thing in the "Change the Organizer" section: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/best-practices-when-using-the-outlook-calendar-HA104004449.aspx .